# Оптимизация вывода консоли в сниппете

Tags: дефект, предложение

Приветствую.
Дублирование вывода старой-доброй консоли без необходимости открывать инспектор - отличная идея, но реализована коряво:
Контейнер вывода (`div.as-console-wrapper`) находится в том же DOOM'е, что и код сниппета, что приводит к [таким вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/639105/2) неприятным эффектам, а именно:

1. На раппер действуют пользовательские стили, а т. к. `div` - популярный тэг, он часто попадает под раздачу нежеланных стилей, см. пример.
2. Через JS его так же легко найти, что может быть неожиданно и неприятно.

---

Решить довольно просто можно через [`Shadow DOM`](http://frontender.info/shadowdom/).
Без особых ухищрений, добраться до содержимого нельзя, что и требуется.

Comment: Очень зрелищный баг.

Comment: А решение предложить? В ответе в виде сниппета :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, решать нужно зная устройство генерации сниппета. Я могу, конечно, но лень. Пусть разрабы фиксят, они-то знают что и как.